# Google Apps Script -TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script

I am try to set value. But it does not work

```
function checkDone(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("1");
  const names = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(String).toString().split(",").flat();
  names.forEach(n => {
    let s = ss.getSheetByName(n);
    let vs = s.getRange(1,31,s.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
    let sv = s.getRange(1,31,sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
    vs.forEach((r,i) => {
      if(r[0] == '' && r[1] != '') {
        sv[i][0] = "OK"
      }
    });
    s.getRange(1,31,sv.length,sv[0].length).setValues(sv);
  });
}
TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
```

sometimes it works, but more often it fails. i don't understand why @@
As far as I know, it's probably because forEach no longer works well on V8

i try to make below code to be faster, here is the code at first

```
function check(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = sh.getSheetByName("1")
  var getNames = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues().filter(String).toString().split(",");
    for (var j = 0; j < getNames.length; j++) {
      var sheetnow = sh.getSheetByName(getNames[j]);
      var last = sh.getSheetByName(getNames[j]).getLastRow();
      for (var i = 1 ; i <= last ; i++ ) {
        var rangeactive = sheetnow.getRange(i ,31).getValue();
        var range = sheetnow.getRange(i ,31)
        var setval = sheetnow.getRange(i ,32);
          if (rangeactive == 1 && setval.getValue() == "") {
              setval.setValue("OK");
          }   
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is let sv = s.getRange(1,31,sh.getLastRow()).getValues(); intended? Shouldn't it be s.getLastRow() since you're working on sheet s? Also, where does "probably because forEach no longer works well on V8" come from?

Comment: sv = s.getRange (1,31, sh.getLastRow ()). GetValues ​​(); is right. I see a lot of people say that hi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing `sv[i][0] = "OK"`, you use an index from `vs` (`i`, which comes from [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) to access an element of `sv`.

But you're using different sheets when calling the method `getLastRow()`, so it's not guaranteed that `vs` and `sv` have the same length.

Because of that, if the number of rows in both of the used sheets (`sh` and `s`) doesn't match, your code will try to access a property of an undefined array element.

In the original code that you added to the edited question, `rangeactive` and `setval` are ranges referring to the same row (`i`, which is based on the number of rows in sheet `sh.getSheetByName(getNames[j])`), so you probably need to do the following change:

From:

```
let sv = s.getRange(1,31,sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
```

To:

```
let sv = s.getRange(1,31,s.getLastRow()).getValues();
```